# Os dados não estão salvando

Tags: php, html

Criei um projeto que contém a parte de *admin* que seleciona as horas para ficar disponível para o cliente e tem a página de contato, quando eu vou primeiro no *admin* e seleciono as horas e clico em atualizar **(botão que eu criei)** ele vai para página de contato e aparece as horas que eu selecionei... agora quando eu clico primeiro na home e depois volto para página de contato as horas que eu selecionei não estão mais lá... a minha dúvida é, deve ser por que eu estou localmente e por isso acontece?

Tenho medo de eu hospedar o site e o problema ainda continar, pelo fato de não esta aparecendo as horas que eu selecionei logo depois de ter dado uma "navegada" no meu site....

Código do PHP e da página que recebe os dados:

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="campo-externo">
                <div class="caixa-registrado col-lg-12">
                    <p>Marca uma visita agora!</p>

                    <form>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <input class="detalhe-campo-velho" type="text" placeholder="Nome">
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <input class="detalhe-campo-velho" type="number" placeholder="Codigo de segurança">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <hr />

                        <form>
                            <div class="campo-agenda-novo">
                                <p class="texto-centro">Agenda disponível</p>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 texto-centro">

                                <?php 

                                        if(isset($_POST["hora"])) {


                                            for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["hora"]); $i++) {


                                    echo " ".$_POST["hora"] [$i]." <input type='radio'/> </br>";

                                    }                                                          
                                        }
                                ?>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        <div class="texto-centro">
                            <button class="botao-confir margin-top20">Confirmar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr class="linha-cinza" />
    </div>
```

Página admin :

```
<form method="post" action="agendamento.php">
    <div class="row texto-centro">
        <div class="col-lg-12 texto-centro">
            <span>10:00</span>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="10:00" name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="um">
            <br />
            <span>10:30</span>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="10:30"  name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="dois">
            <br />
            <span>11:00</span>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="11:00" name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="tres">
            <br />
            <span>11:30</span>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="11:30" name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="quatro">
            <br />
            <span>13:00</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="13:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="cinco">
            <br />
            <span>13:30</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="13:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="seis">
            <br />
            <span>14:00</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="14:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="sete">
            <br />
            <span>14:30</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="14:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="oito">
            <br />
            <span>15:00</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="15:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="dez">
            <br />
            <span>15:30</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="15:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="onze">
            <br />
            <span>16:00</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="16:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="doze">
            <br />
            <span>16:30</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="16:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="treze">
            <br />
            <span>17:00</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="17:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="quatorze">
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row texto-centro margin-top20">
        <button ng-click="atualizar()" value="descobrir">Atualizar</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

Alguém poderia me explicar como funciona... eu sei que para fazer o envio de email através do php ele exige que o site esteja hospedado, ja esse método que fiz não sei se o site precisa de estar hospedado.

Answer (score 2):

A sua página que recebe dados está usando a $_POST para exibir as horas selecionadas. A variável $_POST só existe quando você as envia de um formulário (são os valores inseridos nos campos input). Se você vai da Home->Página que recebe dados, a variável $_POST não estará setada, logo, não terá o que exibir.

Comment: Ah tendi... e como poderia solucionar esse problema... eu precisava salvar essas variaveis pois vai que o usuário queira navegar no site e depois voltar para marcar a hora...

Comment: No caso o mais recomendável é que você salve OS VALORES DAS VARIÁVEIS em um banco de dados. Daí, quando você for exibí-los, basta buscar no banco.
Para saber como fazer isso, basta procurar sobre CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete - ações a se fazer em um banco de dados).

Comment: Mas quando eu salvar os dados da variaveis no banco eu poderei manipular quais dados quero mostrar na outra tela?

Comment: Qualquer dado salvo no banco pode ser manipulado. Por isso recomendei que você lesse sobre CRUD.

Comment: Entendi... obrigado